# Can't get the Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 working on my computer

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, external-soundcard

I recently decided to switch over to Ubuntu for experimentation.
I previously had a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 fully functioning on my Windows OS and was able to record, playback and produce sounds using FL Studio.
But now, I can't get my computer to playback sound through it.
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu all together and I need massive help.

So far I've gotten the computer to recognize that the Scarlett is connected and have install the drivers.
Pulse Audio recognizes that the Scarlett exists but when I check the Port tab to switch it's output to the speakers, it only allows me to put it as analog output. The volume bar moves as sounds play but no sound is coming out of the speakers.
The same applies for the input settings, the volume tab moves as I speak into my mic, but again no sound.

I've checked forums, Everyone seems to point towards getting Qjack for recording sounds. I've installed it and it doesn't seem to recognize any devices. Maybe there's great deal of setting up or something, I don't know.

Comment: If you have not installed `qjackctl` you should do it. It is a lot easier to use than the cli. You should see your interface in the settings there because the 2i2 has a class compliant mode.

Comment: You may wish to use a distro that is configured for audio. Ubuntu Studio Kxstudio - http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/ . kxstudio has Cadence which is a set of graphical applications will configure jack. You can download cadence as a binary from here - http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/Downloads . Once you are up and running you can configure jack manually if you so desire. If you want to configure everything yourself go through - http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration

Comment: Thank guys for the responses. I  have installed the qjack and can see the 2i2. But when I the interface, input and output to the usb(Scarelett 2i2), i get no sound. It is picking up the microphone tho. Also I will look into kxstudio, but i definitely have fl studio working fine on ubuntu, aside from the asio, which is something i will deal with

Answer (score 0):

## Cadence

Definitely try Cadence from KX Studio ... worked for me in similar circumstances.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudioPreparation (instructions plus more features)

Open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T)

**install the very basics :**

```
sudo apt-get install vlc ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntustudio-menu cdrdao
```

**Install needed tools**

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common wget
```

**Enable KXStudio repo (press 'Enter' once asked)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kxstudio-debian/kxstudio
```

**Update software sources**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install kxstudio-repos**

```
sudo apt-get install kxstudio-repos
```

**Update software sources again**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then download the Cadence binary from http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Cadence  (bottom of the site)

In Cadence, make sure to select your sound card in Configure< Driver< Device.  (I also Start the ALSA Midi and PulseAudio JACK Bridges)

I hope that works.

Comment: For someone reason I cannot start the PulseAudio bridge!